# how do you make refined iron on industrial craft 2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-industrialcraft

I tried to make refined iron by cooking it in the furnace but it doesnt work, so if someone knows how then please help.

Comment: Perhaps there are other mods conflicting with the recipe? What modpack are you using?

Comment: If you've got Gregtech, I think that might be a potential culprit, in particular.

Answer (score 3):

in the newest version of IC2 refined iron has been replaced by iron plates which are made with a hammer (and later by the metal former)

craft the hammer with 5 iron ingots in a reversed C and 2 sticks as the handle, then combine an iron ingot with the hammer in a crafting grid. you get 80 uses out of each hammer